# How to use sbtosgi to generate osgi bundle as part of sbt publish task

Tags: scala, osgi, sbt

I'm using the [sbtosgi plugin](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbtosgi) to generate an OSGi bundle from an sbt build using bnd.  The sbtosgi bundle provides the *osgi-bundle* task for generating the bundle.  Using the default configuration for sbtosgi, running *osgi-bundle* from the sbt prompt updates the JAR to include the proper headers, but running *clean package* results in a JAR without OSGi headers.  In Maven speak, I'm trying to do the equivalent of using maven-bundle-plugin with packaging = bundle -- i.e., the main artifact of the project should be an OSGi bundle.

Based on reading the source of sbtosgi plugin, it appears to me that the osgi-bundle task overwrites the JAR created by packageBin.  I tried overriding the definition of packageBin so that it used osgi-bundle task instead of the default task:

```
  packageBin in Compile <<= OsgiKeys.bundle
```

This resulted in a cyclic reference though:

```
[error] Cyclic reference involving 
[error]    {file:project/*:osgi-bundle
[error]    {file:project/compile:full-classpath
[error]    {file:project/compile:exported-products
[error]    {file:project/compile:package-bin
```

I'm rather new to SBT and I'm not sure where to go from here.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like my initial suggestion via Twitter which you used does not work. Sorry for that. But luckily I had Mark Harrah sitting next to me and here comes a working solution:

```
packagedArtifact in (Compile, packageBin) <<= (artifact in (Compile, packageBin), OsgiKeys.bundle).identityMap

artifact in (Compile, packageBin) ~= (_.copy(`type` = "bundle"))
```